# Exclude line which containing strings on the capturing group

Tags: regex

Logs containing below:

```
2018-10-31 14:14:39; dcv0000088; 192.168.48.200; 
 Variable Bindings
      vmwVpxdNewStatus:= Green
      vmwVpxdObjValue:= alarm.FanHealthAlarm - Event: Hardware Health Changed (3131155);
--ENDOFTRAP--
2018-10-31 10:41:49; sb02; 192.168.41.252; 
     Variable Bindings
          sysUpTime:= 2 days 20 hours 18 minutes 24.23 seconds (24590423)
          snmpTrapOID:= FSC-RTP-MIB:iandcAdmin.55.1.3.4.5 (1.3.6.1.4.1.4329.2.55.1.3.4.5)
          iandcAdmin.55.1.1.3.0:= SIP Server not running
          iandcAdmin.55.1.1.7.0:= SIP Server;
--ENDOFTRAP--
```

I would like to capture all text after `Variable Bindings` and before `;` but exclude line containing `sysUpTime....`from the capture.
I use regex:

```
Variable\sBindings\s+(?P<varBind>[^;]+(?!sysUpTime\:=.*))
```

but it still not working. Expected result is:

`varBind=`

```
 vmwVpxdNewStatus:= Green
 vmwVpxdObjValue:= alarm.FanHealthAlarm - Event: Hardware Health Changed (3131155)
```

`varBind=`

```
  snmpTrapOID:= FSC-RTP-MIB:iandcAdmin.55.1.3.4.5 (1.3.6.1.4.1.4329.2.55.1.3.4.5)
  iandcAdmin.55.1.1.3.0:= SIP Server not running
  iandcAdmin.55.1.1.7.0:= SIP Server
```

Please advise. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an optional (non-capturing) group that will match the `sysUpTime` line if it's there, ensuring that it won't be included in the subsequent `varBind` group:

```
Variable\sBindings\s+(?:sysUpTime.+\s+)?(?P<varBind>[^;]+)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/n5zPcr/2

If `sysUpTime` can appear somewhere other than the first line after `Variable Bindings`, then note that any group (or full match) must contain *contiguous* characters from the input - leaving out part of them is not possible without some other method, such as capturing the initial substring, matching the `sysUpTime` line, and then capturing the later substring.

Comment: thanks, i saw it working properly on the regex101. but when i use it on Splunk it seem not working. Maybe i need to looking something else..